# Java String initialization as primitive type

Tags: java

String is an Object. Why it is possible to initialize it the same way as primitive type: String str = "my string";

I was expecting to see initialization by using constructor only: new String("my string");

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046045/java-string-literal-pool-and-string-object) may also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a simplification provided by java. The other alternative would be enormous ugly. Your alternative solution has one simple logical mistake:

```
new String("my string");
```

Just aswell uses a string-literal as simply `"my string"`. The **real** alternative would be

```
new String(new char[]{'m','y',' ',...,'n','g'});
```

Or just the same example using a `byte[]` (deprecated), which would look even worse.

Comment: Thanks, so basically compiler converts that "my string" to char sequence for us?

Comment: @WildGoat There's no conversion required, a `String` literally IS a `CharSequence` in Java, since that's one of the interfaces the `String` class implements.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String()):

> Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.